# ng6: Dynamically form Variable names in html

Tags: angular, typescript

## Component

In my component i have variables like this.

```
i18 = 'server';
i19 = 'database';
i21 = 'share-alt';
i20 = 'battery-full';
i22 = 'soundcloud';
```

## html

this will show var `i18` from the component

```
<fa [name]="[i18]"></fa>
```

this will show var `i18` from the component

```
<fa [name]="i18"></fa>
```

this resolves to "i18" instead of "server"

```
<fa [name]="'i'+category.id"></fa>
```

## question

In the last snippet I am trying to get the value of `i18` from the component with `'i'+category.id` where `category.id` is "18" instead, it prints "i18" the template. how can I write the HTML so the value of `'i'+category.id` is "server"

Comment: please provide the html section which handle these, so we can see your stracture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create variable names dynamically in the template. You could store the values in a `Map` structure:

```
public names = new Map<number,string>([
  [18, "server"],
  [19, "database"],
  [20, "battery-full"],
  [21, "share-alt"],
  [22, "soundcloud"],
]);
```

and retrieve them with the `get` method in the template:

```
<fa [name]="names.get(category.id)"></fa>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5nn31s) for a demo.